# Iterate over map keys

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m using kind of an object map on jQuery

```
  unitPerRestrictions[restriction]= product.quantity.numberOfUnits;
```

What I would like now is iterate over the keys to extract the values and use the key for other business logic. I cannot find a proper way to do this on jQuery 
Map and other implementations that I saw did not works

```
$.map(list, function(obj, index) {
    if(obj.prop2 == "yutu") {
        return index;
    }
})
```

Comment: `Object.keys(list).forEach(function() {...`

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function.

```
var targetKey;
$.each(list, function(key, value) {
    if(value === "yutu") {
        targetKey = key;
    }
});
```

Comment: @paul can you be a little more specific about how it did not work? You mean it didn't find the "yutu" match? Did you step through the debugger?

Comment: it did not go inside the loop. I put a debug inside and is not iterating nothing at all

Comment: Let's verify if "list" is indeed an object, What is the result of `typeof list === 'object'`?

Comment: var test = typeof unitPerRestrictions === 'object' ---> true

Comment: Ok, let's see if "list" has any members then: `Object.keys(list).length`

Comment: Finally I did a workaround, thanks anyway. I give you a vote for the effort ;)